# C++ - What does it mean when you put an ampersand (&) in front of an rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, rvalue-reference, rvalue

So I have this code:

```
foo<T>& foo<T>::operator=(foo&& M) 
{
  if (this != &M)
  {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

and I am quite confused as to what `this != &M` means here. What happens when you try to get the memory address of a rvalue reference? Is that what this code is trying to do?

1. What does `this != &F` do exactly? What does it check?
2. What is the purpose of using an rvalue reference as parameter for an assignment operator?

Sorry if this is dumb. I am quite new to C++ and I am trying to learns how rvalue references work and why they are used in cases like this.

Thanks!

Comment: *One* question per SO question, please.

Comment: The ampersand there is the same as putting an ampersand in front of any identifier: it gives the address of the thing it's applied to.

Comment: (1) - `&M` is the address of the object `M` is bound to. Even though you can't take addresses of temporary objects directly, you can do it using rvalue references. `if (this != &M)` makes sure we're not doing something like `x = std::move(x);`. (2) - Look up *move semantics*. (3) - Nowhere, this assignment operator is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply checking for self-assignment. If the address of the object being passed in is the same as `this` then do nothing.

Comment: Where does the actual "assignment" part happen though? `this` is not being given any new values from the passed parameter (right-hand side) as far as I can see...

Comment: @schy That's correct. This assignment operator is incomplete

Comment: @Schytheron in this case there's no actual assignment to members of the object, but `delete[] m_vec;` *does* change `this`. It is indeed a rather strange (probably wrong) operator implementation..

Comment: @0x499602D2 Oh... well that was anti-climactic. At least I know that I am not crazy then. Thought that there was something weird in the code that I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

At first, it seems you haven't correct view on references. References are some thing like pointers to prevent copying whole of objects in function calls. This is the reason why we use rdferences to objects that may be larg chunk oc memory (like mtrices).
But have some differences with pointers.
After creating a referenc, it seems like a normal variable (no need to *, & to access its value and address)

`this != &M` means **is address of M equal to this?**

It is for checking wheter this object and other one, are same objdcts or not. If yes, just return current object. And if not, clear underlying data... **and copy M's data to current object**, but it seems this implementation is not complete. I don't see copying expressions...